# How to go back to Phonegap/browser once native android Activity is started?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, transition

I have an app developed in Phonegap. For playing Video I have used videoView of native Android.

I have successfully played the video. but now I want that on button click of that activity, I should again go back to Phonegap/Browser screen. But as soon as I click android back button, It closes the application.

Any one have idea how to move from native android to phonegap??

**Edit**

```
super.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run()
{
    final KHS khs = new KHS();
    cordova.getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.second);
    final VideoView videoHolder = (VideoView) cordova.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    khs.nativeVideoPlayer(cordova.getActivity(), VideoPlayer.message, videoHolder);

    final Button btn = (Button)cordova.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.videobutton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity(), "Stop the Video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    videoHolder.stopPlayback();
    khs.hideVideoPlayer();
}
});
                }
            });
```

Comment: try simply super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/mysite.html");

Comment: I another class which is extending CordovaPlugin and hence I am not able to do that.... What is other alternative??

Comment: I have added the code for more reference. How can I call super.loadUrl() from button click event??